# stop gvim from printing the filename onto console

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

In my unix environment when I use gvim to open a file it immediately print the file name onto console. Can someone help me on how to stop gvim from doing this?

```
$ gvim ~/.cshrc.local 
"~/.cshrc.local" 
"~/.cshrc.local" 2L, 291C$username> 

$ gvim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 15 2019 13:18:22)
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the output of `gvim` to `/dev/null`:

```
$ gvim &> /dev/null ~/.cshrc.local
$
```

If you don't want to include the redirection every time, you could create an alias:

```
$ alias gvim='gvim &> /dev/null'
$ gvim ~/.cshrc.local
$
```